# Create PyQGIS standalone application with the help of PyInstaller?

Tags: pyqgis

I created a simple PyQGIS application that consists of one file main_prj.py with the following content:

```
from qgis.core import QgsCoordinateTransform, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem, QgsPointXY, QgsApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys

def main():
    print('Start program')

    qgis_prefix_path = 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis'
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(qgis_prefix_path, True)

    QgsApplication.initQgis()

    cs_3857 = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(3857, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)
    cs_4326 = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)

    transform_4326_3857 = QgsCoordinateTransform()
    transform_4326_3857.setSourceCrs(cs_4326)
    transform_4326_3857.setDestinationCrs(cs_3857)

    pnt = QgsPointXY(37.384, 49.764)
    pn1 = transform_4326_3857.transform(pnt)
    print(pn1)
    input('Press Enter to stop')
    QgsApplication.exitQgis()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Actually, the app only calculates the coordinates defined in epsg:4326 into coordinates in epsg:3857
The output generated in Pycharm looks as follows

Start program

Press Enter to stop

Process finished with exit code 0

Then I try to generate executable using PyInstaller
pyinstaller main_prj.py And get the following traceback:

```
 1. 114 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4 114 INFO: Python: 3.6.0 115 INFO:   
    Platform: Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0 119 INFO: wrote   
    d:\Users\Bogomolov\Qgis\Test_prj\main_prj.spec 167 INFO: UPX is   
    available. 169 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths   
    ['d:\\Users\\Bogomolov\\Qgis\\Test_prj',   
    'd:\\Users\\Bogomolov\\Qgis\\Test_prj'] 170 INFO: checking Analysis 
    170 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent 
    171 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph... 175 INFO:   
    Initializing module graph hooks... 177 INFO: Analyzing   
    base_library.zip ... 3121 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
    3133    INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent 
    assemblies of final executable   required by   
    c:\osgeo4w64\apps\python36\python.exe 3174 WARNING: lib not found:  
    api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of   
    c:\osgeo4w64\apps\python36\python.exe 3206 WARNING: lib not found:  
    api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of   
    c:\osgeo4w64\apps\python36\python.exe 3242 WARNING: lib not found:  
    api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of   
    c:\osgeo4w64\apps\python36\python.exe 3281 WARNING: lib not found:  
    api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of   
    c:\osgeo4w64\apps\python36\python.exe 3319 WARNING: lib not found:  
    api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of   
    c:\osgeo4w64\apps\python36\python.exe 3357 WARNING: lib not found:  
    api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of   
    C:\Windows\system32\vcruntime140.dll 3393 WARNING: lib not found:   
    api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of   
    C:\Windows\system32\vcruntime140.dll 3430 WARNING: lib not found:   
    api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of   
    C:\Windows\system32\vcruntime140.dll 3466 WARNING: lib not found:   
    api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of   
    C:\Windows\system32\vcruntime140.dll 3499 WARNING: lib not found:   
    api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of   
    C:\Windows\system32\vcruntime140.dll 3611 WARNING: lib not found:   
    api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of   
    c:\OSGEO4W64\bin\python36.dll 3645 WARNING: lib not found:   
    api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of   
    c:\OSGEO4W64\bin\python36.dll 3678 WARNING: lib not found:   
    api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of   
    c:\OSGEO4W64\bin\python36.dll 3710 WARNING: lib not found:   
    api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of   
    c:\OSGEO4W64\bin\python36.dll 3741 WARNING: lib not found:   
    api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of   
    c:\OSGEO4W64\bin\python36.dll 3774 WARNING: lib not found:   
    api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of   
    c:\OSGEO4W64\bin\python36.dll 3806 WARNING: lib not found:   
    api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of   
    c:\OSGEO4W64\bin\python36.dll 3840 WARNING: lib not found:   
    api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of   
    c:\OSGEO4W64\bin\python36.dll 3875 WARNING: lib not found:   
    api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll dependency of   
    c:\OSGEO4W64\bin\python36.dll 3907 WARNING: lib not found:   
    api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of   
    c:\OSGEO4W64\bin\python36.dll 3941 WARNING: lib not found:   
    api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of   
    c:\OSGEO4W64\bin\python36.dll 3976 WARNING: lib not found:   
    api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of   
    c:\OSGEO4W64\bin\python36.dll 3981 INFO: Caching module hooks...

    3987    INFO: Analyzing d:\Users\Bogomolov\Qgis\Test_prj\main_prj.py

    4026    INFO: Loading module hooks... 4027 INFO: Loading module hook

    "hook-encodings.py"... 4128 INFO: Loading module hook   
    "hook-pydoc.py"... 4130 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.py"...

    4214 WARNING: Cannot read QLibraryInfo output: raised Expecting   
    value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) when decoding: Traceback (most
    recent    call last):   File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
    ImportError: DLL    load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.
    Traceback (most recent call    last):   File
    "c:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in   
    _run_module_as_main    "__main__", mod_spec)   File "c:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code   
    exec(code, run_globals)   File
    "c:\OSGEO4W64\apps\Python36\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py",   
    line 9, in <module>   File   
    "c:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py",
    line 111, in run    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))  
    File
    "c:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py",
    line 63, in run_build   
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file,
    **kwargs)   File "c:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py",
    line 838, in main    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'),
    kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))   File   
    "c:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py",
    line 784, in build    exec(text, spec_namespace)   File "<string>",
    line 17, in <module>   File   
    "c:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py",
    line 241, in __init__    self.__postinit__()   File
    "c:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py",
    line 158, in __postinit__    self.assemble()   File
    "c:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py",
    line 500, in assemble    module_hook.post_graph()   File
    "c:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\imphook.py",
    line 410, in post_graph    self._load_hook_module()   File
    "c:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\imphook.py",
    line 377, in _load_hook_module    self.hook_module_name,
    self.hook_filename)   File
    "c:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py",
    line 736, in importlib_load_source    return
    mod_loader.load_module()   File "<frozen
    importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 399, in _check_name_wrapper   
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 823, in   
    load_module   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line   

    682, in load_module   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line

    251,    in _load_module_shim   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>",

    line    675, in _load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line

    655, in    _load_unlocked   File "<frozen
    importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module   File
    "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205,    in
    _call_with_frames_removed   File    "c:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-PyQt5.py",
    line 23, in <module>   
    collect_system_data_files(pyqt5_library_info.location['PrefixPath'],
    File   
    "c:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py",
    line 67, in __getattr__    qli = json.loads(json_str)   File
    "c:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in
    loads    return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File
    "c:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in
    decode    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File
    "c:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in   
    raw_decode    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value)
    from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1
    column 1 (char    0)
```

What I have done wrong or have not taken into consideration?

Comment: I got the same problem. Have U fixed this?

Comment: Actually not. I just postponed the solution to the problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/157353)

Comment: I do not understand. I asked the question and am waiting for an answer.

Comment: Sorry Dan C. Your comment does not seem to have addressed me.